# Export function that inside a function ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

Iam trying to call a function that inside a function but when I write export for the function it show me error

```html
const ProfileContent = () => {
    const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
    const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState(null);
    const [graphDatah, setGraphDatah] = useState(null);

    function RequestProfileData() {
        // Silently acquires an access token which is then attached to a request for MS Graph data
        instance.acquireTokenSilent({
            ...loginRequest,
            account: accounts[0]
        }).then((response) => {
            callMsGraph(response.accessToken).then(response => setGraphData(response));
        });
    }

 //--------------------------

   function takesheet() 
     {
        return (
        // Silently acquires an access token which is then attached to a request for MS Graph data
        instance.acquireTokenSilent({
            account: accounts[0]
        }).then((response) => {
            PostData(response.accessToken).then(response => setGraphDatah(response));
        })
        );
    }
```

Iam trying to export takesheet function but Iam getting this error , I want to call takesheet in another file .
[image]

Comment: Are u trying to export a function inside of a component?

Comment: Its a function inside another function

Comment: you can look at closure in javascript.

Comment: that's not allowed in javascript. You can extract the function you want to import out of the component and pass everything you need as props then you can import it in multiple places.
```
export const takesheet = ({instance,accounts,PostData, setGraphDatah }) =>  {
        return (...)
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code will help you. We have to return a value when we use function.

```
  const a=()=>{
    function b(){
        console.log("HELLO")
    }
    return b
   }
let test=a();
test()
```